# C++ code showing time limit exceeded and runtime error

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search

The question was to find Floor in a Sorted Array and my code is not passing on the runtime test case. Please help me out here by telling me an optimized approach (it would be nice to find an answer without the use of STL Libraries).

**This Here is my code:**

```
int findFloor(vector<long long> v, long long n, long long x)
{
    long long start = 0, end = n - 1;
    long long res = -1;

    while (start <= end)
    {
        long long mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        if (v[mid] == x)
        {
            res = v[mid];
        }
        else if (v[mid] < x)
        {
            res = v[mid];
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        else if (v[mid] > x)
        {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` is part of the standard C++ library that originated with Stepanov's STL from the early 1990s.

Comment: "It would be nice to find an answer without the use of STL Libraries" why ?

Comment: The refusal of beginners to use containers from the c++ standard and instead using random things from C, which are must objectively harder and more error prone to use, always confuses me.

Comment: Passing the vector by reference may be a good start. Also, shouldn"t the last `else if` just be an `else`?

Comment: It's one thing to be learning about sorting algorithms and their pros and cons, but this isn't that. It seems rather silly to refuse to use tools that are available to you. That's like a roofer refusing to use a nail gun. Why would they ever do that?

Comment: Even here, you're bothering to pass the size of the vector as a separate parameter? The vector knows its size already.

Comment: *Please help me out here by telling me an optimised approach* -- Use [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) which in essence what you are attempting to do with all of that code.  -- *The question was to find Floor in a Sorted Array and my code is not passing on the runtime test case* -- Is this from a "competitive coding" website?  If so, you could have won the "competition" by using what was suggested in the previous comments.

Comment: @user438383 it takes a whole lot of effort to learn C++ the wrong way, so once you can get along with it there is quite some resistance to give up all learned and learn the right way, especially because it takes a whole lot of effort to learn the right way ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a problem, so..

Let's say we have an array, that contains `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` these numbers and we're finding the number **4** in it (x = 4).

In our case:

**start = 0;**
**end = 4;**
**mid = 2;**

At the first iteration, **v[mid] < x** and **start = mid + 1 (3)**

At the second iteration start = 3, end = 4, mid = 3, so v[3] == 4 this is true, you set **res = v[mid]** and after that `start` is always 3 and the loop runs endlessly, you need to break the loop

Answer (score 0):

> (it would be nice to find an answer without the use of STL Libraries)

If so then I would write an *iterative binary search* this way while keeping the algorithm very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>


[[ nodiscard ]] constexpr std::ptrdiff_t
binarySearch( const long long* const array,
              std::ptrdiff_t lowerBound,
              std::ptrdiff_t upperBound,
              const long long target) noexcept
{
    std::ptrdiff_t result { };

    while ( lowerBound <= upperBound )
    {
        std::ptrdiff_t mid { lowerBound + ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2 };

        if ( array[ mid ] == target )
        {
            return result = mid;
        }
        else if ( array[ mid ] < target )
        {
            lowerBound = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            upperBound = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return result = -1;
}

int main( )
{
    const long long arr[] { 3, 44, 44, 1000, 1050 };
    const std::ptrdiff_t lowerBound { 0 };
    const std::ptrdiff_t upperBound { std::ssize( arr ) - 1 };
    const long long target { 1000 };

    std::ptrdiff_t resultIndex { binarySearch( arr, lowerBound,
                                               upperBound, target ) };

    if ( resultIndex == -1 )
    {
        std::cout << "The element <<" << target
                  << ">> is not present in the array\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The element <<" << target << ">> is present at index "
                  << resultIndex << " of the array\n";
    }
}
```

*Sample input/output:*

```
The element <<1000>> is present at index 3 of the array
```

Note: The above code snippet only compiles using C++20 [(live)](https://godbolt.org/z/EbEj5MTrW).

The above code also works with other contiguous container types such as `std::vector`, `std::array`, etc.

---

Note: Some of the keywords used above (such as `[[ nodiscard ]]`, `constexpr`, `noexcept`) can be removed without causing an issue. However, I put them there for the sake of robustness.

---

A more modern solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <span>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>


[[ nodiscard ]] constexpr std::ptrdiff_t
binarySearch( const std::span<const long long> array,
              const long long target) noexcept
{
    std::ptrdiff_t result;

    std::ptrdiff_t lowerBound { };
    std::ptrdiff_t upperBound { std::distance( std::cbegin( array ), std::cend( array ) ) - 1 };

    while ( lowerBound <= upperBound )
    {
        std::ptrdiff_t mid { lowerBound + ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2 };

        if ( array[ mid ] == target )
        {
            return result = mid;
        }
        else if ( array[ mid ] < target )
        {
            lowerBound = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            upperBound = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return result = -1;
}

int main( )
{
    const std::array<long long, 5> arr { 3, 44, 44, 1000, 1050 };
    const auto lowerBound { std::cbegin( arr ) };
    const auto upperBound { std::cend( arr ) };
    const long long target { 44 };

    std::ptrdiff_t resultIndex { binarySearch( { lowerBound, upperBound } , target ) };

    if ( resultIndex == -1 )
    {
        std::cout << "The element <<" << target
                  << ">> is not present in the span\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The element <<" << target << ">> is present at index "
                  << resultIndex << " of the span\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the code. Helped a lot

Comment: @Prathu You're welcome. Also consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick icon if it was helpful.